# Understanding Doctrine Cascade Operations

Tags: php, doctrine, cascade

I want to check my understanding of cascade operations on Doctrine associations. For the purpose of this question, I have two models: `Customer` and `Insuree`.

If I define a many to many relationship between a `Customer` and `Insuree` and set `cascade{"all"}`, I understand that this will:

- Adding a new insuree to a customer will persist this insuree and create an association in the join table.
- Removing an insuree from the collection will detach the insuree from the customer and detach the customer from the insuree.
- Deleting the customer will delete all insurees associated with the customer.

This is the definition of the association on `Customers`.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Insuree", inversedBy="customers", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_insuree",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="insuree_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $insurees;
```

If I define the inverse many to many relationship between an `Insuree` and `Customer` and set `cascade{"all"}`, I understand that this will:

- Adding a new customer to an insuree will persist this customer and create an association in the join table.
- Removing a customer from the collection will detach the customer from the insuree and detach the insuree from the customer.
- Deleting the insuree will delete all customers associated with it.

This is the definition of the association on `Insurees`.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="insurees", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $customers;
```

If I then define the relationship as to cascade on persist, merge and detach - deleting the insuree will not delete all associated customers - it will only remove the associations between the insuree and its customers?

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="insurees", cascade={"persist", "merge", "detach"})
 */
protected $customers;
```

Comment: Can't you check if your understanding of the cascading relationships is correct by creating some `Customer`s and `Insuree`s and start deleting/adding records?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

**persist & remove**

You are correct about `cascade={"persist"}` meaning that persisting entity A, Doctrine will also persist all B entities in the Collection.

You are also correct about `cascade={"remove"}` meaning that removing entity A, Doctrine will also remove all B entities in the Collection.
But I doubt you would ever want to use this on a ManyToMany association, because when you remove entity A that cascades this operation to all B entities, those B entities might be associated to other A entities.

**detach & merge**

You are *not* correct about `cascade={"detach"}` and `cascade={"merge"}`:

Adding/removing entities from the Collection is something *you* need to do (in your code). Read about that [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html).

*Detach* means that you detach an entity from the EntityManager. The EntityManager will no longer manage that entity. This makes a detached entity the same as a newly instantiated entity, except that it's already in the database (but you made the EntityManager unaware of that).

In other words: `cascade={"detach"}` means that detaching entity A, Doctrine will also detach all B entities in the Collection.

*Merge* is the opposite of *detach*: You will merge a detached entity back into the EntityManager.
Do note that `merge()` will actually return a *new* managed object, the detached object you passed to it remains unmanaged.

Comment: It should be noted that calling `merge()` will cause the unmanaged entity to overwrite the properties of the managed entity. Upon `persist()`, the now managed entity will perform an update against that entity's table.

This can lead to unexpected data loss.