# ZF2 - Doctrine - Delete an entity persistent

Tags: php, zend-framework2

started working with doctrine in ZF2 and need to delete an entity from persistence.

```
$result = $em->getRepository('zmpim\Entity\Collection')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id));
    $products = $result->getProducts();
    $this->assertSame(1, count($products));
    $this->assertSame(3, count($products[0]->getFields()));
    $em->remove($result);
    $em->persist($result);
    $em->flush($result);
```

The example is in a unit test. I would expect, that the entity is deleted after it. But the entity and some OneToMany entities are still there.

cu n00n

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `cascade={"remove"}`. Take a look at this question:

[Understanding Doctrine Cascade Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612664/understanding-doctrine-cascade-operations)

You define the cascade option in your association annotation of your entity like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(/* ... */ cascade={"remove"})
 */
```

This works with every kind of association of course.

Doctrine Documentation:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

In a separate unit test, you'd get the entities metadata to check for the cascade specification of the association by calling something like:

```
$mapping = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('zmpim\Entity\Collection')
    ->getAssociationMapping('products');
$this->assertTrue($mapping['isCascadeRemove']);
```

Comment: tried, and nice to test the mapping, but it does not fail. It seems correct. It is not deleting the entity where the product collection is a member...