# Symfony Doctrine - Make fixtures with ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, relationship, fixtures

I use Symfony 4.2 with Doctrine and I want to create fixtures with ManyToMany relationships with two entities :

- Organization
- Project

But when I load fixtures the join table (organization_project) is always empty. So, I don't know if my relationships is good.

For resume :

- Many organizations have many projects
- Many projects have many organizations

**Database view**

[image: database view]

Here my `Organization` entity

```php
class Organization
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Project", mappedBy="organizations")
     */
    private $projects;

    /**
     * @return Collection|Project[]
     */
    public function getProjects(): Collection
    {
        return $this->projects;
    }

    public function addProject(Project $project): self
    {
        if (!$this->projects->contains($project)) {
            $this->projects[] = $project;
            $project->addOrganization($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProject(Project $project): self
    {
        if ($this->projects->contains($project)) {
            $this->projects->removeElement($project);
            $project->removeOrganization($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here my `Project` entity :

```php
class Project
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Organization", inversedBy="projects")
     */
    private $organizations

    /**
     * @return Collection|Organization[]
     */
    public function getOrganizations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->organizations;
    }

    public function addOrganization(Organization $organization): self
    {
        if (!$this->organizations->contains($organization)) {
            $this->organizations[] = $organization;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrganization(Organization $organization): self
    {
        if ($this->organizations->contains($organization)) {
            $this->organizations->removeElement($organization);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Here my `Organization` fixture :

```php
class OrganizationFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public const ORGANIZATION_REFERENCE = 'organization-';

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $organization = new Organization();
        $this->addReference(self::ORGANIZATION_REFERENCE.'0', $organization);
        $organization->addProject($this->getReference('project-0'));

        $manager->persist($organization);
        $manager->flush();
    }

     public function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
            ProjectFixtures::class
        );
    }
}
```

Here my `Project` fixture :

```php
class ProjectFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public const PROJECT_REFERENCE = 'project-';

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $project = new Project();
        $this->addReference(self::PROJECT_REFERENCE.'0', $project);

        $manager->persist($project);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: is maybe your table emprty? can u give as more info in which point is failing?

Comment: In my join table (organization_project), the data don't appear after I load my fixtures. Besides, I have no error in my console. 
I up my post with database screen

Comment: yes but your Organization_project table is empty. Maybe the join does not find any record?

Comment: Thank you I resolve my problem. My organization entity wasn't owning side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Organization` is not [owning side](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany) of the relationship. It does not hold knowledge of joining table (in `ManyToOne` it would be about who is holding foreign key). Also you don't specify [cascading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612664/understanding-doctrine-cascade-operations) on `persist`, so associated entities on not owning side won't be persisted. So for your current fixture structure best association direction would be like this.

```
class Organization
{
...

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Project", inversedBy="organizations", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="organization_project") # this one is not necessary
                                                       putting here for reference
     */
    private $projects;
...
]
```

```
class Project
{
...
    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Organization", mappedBy="projects", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $organizations;
...
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! So if I understood, in ManyToMany we have two owner side and when we use inversedBy in entity, this entity is owner ?

Comment: yes, though the not owning side can be still persisted when using `cascade={"persist"}`, but by logic of your fixture it's better to have owning side on `Organization`